# Salesforce external object (oData) and array in result

Tags: externalobjects, odata

I'm having a problem configuring an external object. We have an oData API which allows us to retrieve order information and in this result we have a product table. When I configure the external object, Salesforce tells me the products field is a long text whereas in the json result it is an array of several values. Is it possible to force the reading of this table or I have to go through several different URLs ?

Example, in product fields shows is (and not the data) :
[org.apache.olingo.odata40.commons.core.data.LinkedComplexValueImpl@xxx, org.apache.olingo.odata40.commons.core.data.LinkedComplexValueImpl@xxx, org.apache.olingo.odata40.commons.core.data.LinkedComplexValueImpl@xxx]

Here, the json result and we want show "notes" and "products" in UI Salesforce like related list :
url : https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xapi/api/unified-odata-xapi/Order?$filter=(OrderId eq 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
or this url get array products only (in array value[]) :
https://xxxxxx/xapi/api/unified-odata-xapi/Order?$filter=(OrderId eq 'XXXXXXXXX')&$select=Products

````
"@odata.context": xxxxxx
        "value": [
        {
            "OrderId": "XXXXXX",
            "DeliveryTeamName": "TEST",
            "ETA": "2023-06-16T07:34:00Z",
            "RealDeliveryTime": null,
            "Status": "Terminé",
            "CancelReason": null,
            "DeliveryPlatform": "XXXX",
            "OrderSite": "XXX",
            "EventDate": "2023-06-14T12:44:11Z",
            "CheckinTime": "2023-06-14T12:43:53Z",
            "ETL": "2023-06-16T07:44:00Z",
            "CheckoutTime": "2023-06-14T12:44:08Z",
            "NoEarlierThan": "2023-06-16T06:00:00Z",
            "NoLaterThan": "2023-06-16T11:00:00Z",
            "TimeOnSite": 0,
            "Products": [
                {
                    "ProductCode": "XXXXX",
                    "ProductName": "Ref",
                    "PreparedQuantity": 1,
                    "DeliveredQuantity": 1,
                    "RejectedQuantity": 0,
                    "ProductPending": false
                }
            ],
            "Notes": [
                {
                    "CreatedAt": "2023-06-14T12:37:31Z",
                    "UserId": "XXX",
                    "Comment": "XXXX",
                    "PictureUrl": null
                },
                {
                    "CreatedAt": "2023-06-14T12:37:31Z",
                    "UserId": "XXXX",
                    "Comment": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                    "PictureUrl": null
                },
                {
                    "CreatedAt": "2023-06-14T12:44:04Z",
                    "UserId": "XXXX",
                    "Comment": null,
                    "PictureUrl": "XXX.jpeg"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "OrderId": "XXXXXX",
            "DeliveryTeamName": "TEST",
            "ETA": "2023-06-16T07:34:00Z",
            "RealDeliveryTime": null,
            "Status": "Terminé",
            "CancelReason": null,
            "DeliveryPlatform": "XXXX",
            "OrderSite": "XXX",
            "EventDate": "2023-06-14T12:44:11Z",
            "CheckinTime": "2023-06-14T12:43:53Z",
            "ETL": "2023-06-16T07:44:00Z",
            "CheckoutTime": "2023-06-14T12:44:08Z",
            "NoEarlierThan": "2023-06-16T06:00:00Z",
            "NoLaterThan": "2023-06-16T11:00:00Z",
            "TimeOnSite": 0,
            "Products": [
                {
                    "ProductCode": "XXXXX",
                    "ProductName": "Ref",
                    "PreparedQuantity": 1,
                    "DeliveredQuantity": 1,
                    "RejectedQuantity": 0,
                    "ProductPending": false
                }
            ],
            "Notes": [
                {
                    "CreatedAt": "2023-06-14T12:37:31Z",
                    "UserId": "XXX",
                    "Comment": "XXXX",
                    "PictureUrl": null
                },
                {
                    "CreatedAt": "2023-06-14T12:37:31Z",
                    "UserId": "XXXX",
                    "Comment": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                    "PictureUrl": null
                },
                {
                    "CreatedAt": "2023-06-14T12:44:04Z",
                    "UserId": "XXXX",
                    "Comment": null,
                    "PictureUrl": "XXX.jpeg"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}```
````